# Using a PostGIS Layer in QField

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, qfield

I am trying to use a PostGIS layer in QField and somehow, i can not manage it to work.
My goal is to collect pointdata via QField using a PostGIS-layer so all collected data are available in the postgres database after synchronisation.

I set up a new database using pgAdmin with the PostGIS extension and connected the database to a QGIS project. I also set up a layer in PostGIS which should be the one that gets 'filled' via QField. Whenever i upload the project to QField, the PostGIS layer is converted into a geopackage and every data added via QField gets shown in the Geopackage but doesn't affect the layer in my database. I am pretty sure i am missing severe steps, settings or logic but since it is my first time using PostGIS/Postgres i don't really found a helpful solution or tutorial on a setup like this.

How can i get Qfield to effect the layer in the database directly?

Comment: Taking a really quick look at the QField documentation they support QField Sync or Qfield Cloud. The Sync is the offline option, Cloud being the online option which is the supported way to do what you want, Reading this https://docs.qfield.org/reference/qfieldcloud/specs/ postgis is supported through QField cloud. I  suspect live updating a postgis database without using QField Cloud is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the previous answer states, QfieldCloud does offer this feature, not realtime, but each time you Push Changes, it will write them to PostGIS layers.  I assume a self hosted QfieldCloud would also do this.

I got impatient trying to get QfieldCloud (hosted) to connect to my self hosted Postgresql, so I am using the QfieldSync QGIS plugin to set up a proof of concept demo that functions as you describe.  I plan to try QfieldCloud self-hosted next.

You must set the PostGIS layer's QField properties -> "Cable layer action" to "Directly access data source".

With the PostGIS layer working in QGIS, you use Plugins -> QfieldSync -> Package for QField

You will likely need to export an authentication file and put in QField/auth folder on Android, to allow QField to login to PostgreSQL.

You will need to transfer the packaged folder to the Android device under Imported Projects.

When adding a point feature in QField, you will see it show up in QGIS if you zoom in or out to trigger a refresh.

I don't expect this to work well if the network connection from QFIELD to Postgres is interrupted, but if you can sort that out, it promises to be SUPER AWESOME.

As a bonus, QGIS does use PostgreSQL's NOTIFY event system to trigger layer redraws.  I suspect a clever SQL trigger could detect QField's updates, and send a NOTIFY to give near instant updates.